# Why does sending consecutive UDP messages cause messages to arrive late?

Tags: python, c, linux, multithreading, sockets

I've written a server python script in Windows 7 to send Ethernet UDP packets to a UNIX system running a C client receiving program that sends the message back to the server. However, sometimes (not always) a message in the last port (and always the last port) that python sends to won't arrive until the next batch of 4 messages is sent. This causes the timing of the message received for the last port incorrect to when it was sent, and **I cannot have two messages back to back on the same port**.

I have been able to verify this in `Wireshark` by locating two messages that arrived around the same time because the one that wasn't received was processed with the other. I have also checked the timing right after the `recv()` function and it shows a long delay and then a short delay because it basically had two packets received.

**Things I have done to try to fix this**, but has help me explain the problem or how to solve it: I can add a delay in between each sendto() and I will successfully send and receive all messages with correct timing but I want the test to work the way I've written it below; I've increased the priority of the receive thread thinking that my Ethernet receive was not getting signal to pick up the package or that some process was taking too long, but this didn't work and 20ms should be WAY more than necessary to process the data; I have removed ports C and D, then port B misses messages (Only having one port doesn't caause issues), I thought reducing the number of ports would improve timing; Sending to a dummy PORTE immediately after PORTD lets me receive all of the messages with correct timing (I assume the problem is transferred to PORTE); I have also reproduced the python script in a UNIX environment and C code and have had the same issue, pointing me to a receiving issue; I've also set my recv function to time out every 1ms hoping that it could recover somehow even though the timing would be off a bit, but I still saw messages back to back. I've also checked that no UDP packets have been dropped and that the buffer is large enough to hold those 4 messages. Any new ideas would help.

This is the core of the code, the python script will send 4 packets. One 20 byte message to a corresponding waiting thread in C and delay for 20ms

A representation of the python code looks something like

```
msg_cnt = 5000 
while cnt < msg_cnt:
   UDPsocket.sendto(data, (IP, PORTA))
   UDPsocket.sendto(data, (IP, PORTB))
   UDPsocket.sendto(data, (IP, PORTC))
   UDPsocket.sendto(data, (IP, PORTD))

   time.sleep(.02)
   cnt++
```

The C code has 4 threads waiting to receive on their corresponding ports. Essentially each thread should receive its packet, process it, and send back to the server. This process should take less than 20ms before the next set of messages arrive

```
void * receiveEthernetThread(){
     uint8_t ethRxBuff[1024];
     if((byteCnt = recv(socketForPort, ethRxBuff, 1024, 0)) < 0){
         perror("recv")
     }else{
        //Process Data, cannot have back to back messages on the same port
        //Send back to the server
     }
}
```

Comment: So if I'm reading this correctly, what you see on wireshark is that the messages from Python are always properly spaced. Is that true?

Comment: As far as sending, yes. Wireshark will show nanosecond delays between the burst of 4 messages and then a 20ms delay perfectly. However, in the receiving there are cases where the messages from the last port seem to have come back to back. Testing the timing right after the recv() has shown that lets say I send one group of four, then another. If the first group missed the last port I will see a large delay(about 40ms showing the next message come in) since it last entered that thread and then a fast delay meaning it basically entered the thread twice.

Comment: UDP doesn't make any guarantees about ordering of packets, or even that all packets are delivered. If you need these properties you need to either build them youself, use a library which provides them on top of UDP (e.g., QUIC), or use a different protocol (e.g., TCP). As for timing issues, there is probably some buffering going on (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bufferbloat).

Comment: Thank you! I will look into bufferbloat, seems like it could be part of the issue and it sounds similar to my initial conclusions about the issue. It's definitely related between speed and time. Unfortunately, I am stuck with UDP.  I have tried up to 1 second of delay as well and still come across the same issue.

Comment: Can you check the effect of processor affinity on the receiving end? This would be the taskset command, basically pinning the server process to a specific cpu/core. Here is an excerpt from the man page which may be relevant: the scheduler attempts to keep processes on the same CPU as long as practical for performance reasons. Therefore, forcing a specific CPU affinity is useful only in certain applications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out the reason I was missing messages a while back and wanted to answer my question. I was running the program on a Zynq-7000 and didn't realize this would be an issue.

In the Xilinx Zynq-7000-TRM, there is a known issue describing:

" It is possible to have the last frame(s) stuck in the RX FIFO with the software having no way to get the last frame(s) out of there. The GEM only initiates a descriptor request when it receives another frame. Therefore, when a frame is in the FIFO and a descriptor only becomes available at a later time and no new frames arrive, there is no way to get that frame out or even know that it exists.

This issue does not occur under typical operating conditions. Typical operating conditions are when the system always has incoming Ethernet frames. The above mentioned issue occurs when the MAC stops receiving the Ethernet frames.

Workaround: There is no workaround in the software except to ensure a continual flow of Ethernet frames."

Was fixed basically by having continuous incoming Ethernet traffic, sorry for missing that crucial information.

Answer (score 0):

> This causes the timing of the message received for the last port
>   incorrect to when it was sent, and I cannot have two messages back to
>   back on the same port.

The short explanation is you are using UDP, and that protocol gives no guarantees about delivery or order.

That aside, what you are describing most definitely sounds like a buffering issue. Unfortunately, there is no real way to "flush" a socket.

You will either need to use a protocol that guarantees what you need (TCP), or implement your needs on top of UDP.

I believe your real problem though is how the data is being parsed on the server side. If your application is completely dependent on a 20ms interval of four separate packets from the network, that's just asking for trouble. If it's possible, I would fix that rather than attempt fixing (normal) socket buffering issues.

A hacky solution though, since I love hacky things:

Set up a fifth socket on the server. After sending your four time-sensitive packets, send "enough" packets to the fifth port to force any remaining time-sensitive packets through. What is "enough" packets is up to you. You can send a static number, assuming it will work, or have the fifth port send you a message back the moment it starts recv-ing.

Comment: Just because there are no guarantees, doesn't mean packets are dropped for no reason. Yes, on the Internet, you might not *know* the reason. But on a fast LAN it should only be caused by congestion.

Comment: I wasn't talking about packets getting dropped or congestion. When I said delivery, what I had in mind was the fact that TCP has the `TCP_NODELAY` flag, which can help push packets through the buffer (but even still doesn't guarantee that).